# ByBit API: is there a way to ensure stop loss order will be executed as "limit"

Tags: python, api, bybit

I am coding up a python bot that helps for scalping. One of my functions, is that once a button is clicked a stop loss 0.04% below the market price will automatically be placed. However due to the closeness of the stop loss, it often gets executed straight away as a market order. On the Bybit user interface there is a post only option, which ensures orders will be processed as limit orders.

Is there a way to implement a function or attribute in my code that will enable me to achieve this functionality.

this function was created so I am able to quickly exit the trade with a limit order, less fees.

Current stoploss setting code

```
if option == 1:
    response = client.LinearPositions.LinearPositions_tradingStop(symbol="BTCUSDT", side=type, stop_loss=sl).result()
    check_for_errors_sl_tp(response)
```

Comment: Are you setting `order_type` to `limit`? https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/inverse/#order-type-order_type

Comment: have you solved? Can you post the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In create order parameters Set time_in_force ='PostOnly'